# X-FRAME-OPTIONS header missing on step1.html of Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, penetration-testing

our security and pen test team reported one issue that the below resource is missing **x-frame-options** header?

Any suggestions or thoughts why only this page alone missing that header even though it is set at Keycloak console?

<keycloak-domain/auth/realms//protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html

Keycloak version: 21.1.2

The realm security defenses setting already configured but still it is reported as an issue.